# Brand Wise Top Selling 3 Items Using LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I need to write a query in LINQ which will show the `Brand` Wise Top selling 3 items.
My result would be like this

[image: Result]

How to write this query in LINQ can anybody help please.

Regards,
Ajith

Comment: Show your objects and what you have tried?..

Comment: "I've tried nothing and I'm all outta ideas!"

Comment: We're not here to write code for you. [ask]

Comment: My Sql query is something like this

select *
from
(
 select brand,item,sum(qty) as qty,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by brand order by sum(qty) desc) as row_num
 from sales
 group by brand,item
)t
where row_num <= 3 
order by brand asc,qty desc

Comment: @AjithCholayil - sql is fine but you are asking for linq. Please Show what have you tried in linq

Answer (score 0):

You should combine OrderByDesc and Take to get the three highest items in the collection. If you want to want to see the results per brand, you need to add a GroupBy statement to your query.

Here's an example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Brand> brands = new List<Brand>()
        {

            new Brand() {Name = "Brand 1", Item = "Item1", Qty = 200}, 
                new Brand() {Name = "Brand 1", Item = "Item1", Qty = 100}, 
                new Brand(){Name = "Brand 1", Item = "Item3", Qty = 98}, 
                new Brand() {Name = "Brand 1", Item = "Item4", Qty = 95}, 
                new Brand() {Name = "Brand 2", Item = "Item5", Qty = 150}, 
                new Brand() {Name = "Brand 2", Item = "Item6", Qty = 125}, 
                new Brand() {Name = "Brand 2", Item = "Item7", Qty = 120}};

        Console.WriteLine("Top items for all ");
        var topOfAll = brands.OrderByDescending(x => x.Qty).Take(3);        
        foreach(Brand brand in topOfAll)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(brand.Name + " " + brand.Item + " - " + brand.Qty);
        }

        IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Brand>> grouped = brands.GroupBy(x => x.Name);
        foreach (IGrouping<string, Brand> groupedBrand in grouped)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Top items for " + groupedBrand.Key);
            IEnumerable<Brand> top = groupedBrand.Select(x => x).OrderByDescending(x => x.Qty).Take(3);
            foreach (Brand i in top)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i.Name + " " + i.Item + " - " + i.Qty);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Brand
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Item
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int Qty
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

The result of this sample is:

`Top items for all 
Brand 1 Item1 - 200
Brand 2 Item5 - 150
Brand 2 Item6 - 125
Top items for Brand 1
Brand 1 Item1 - 200
Brand 1 Item1 - 100
Brand 1 Item3 - 98
Top items for Brand 2
Brand 2 Item5 - 150
Brand 2 Item6 - 125
Brand 2 Item7 - 120`

Here's a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KCdcEH) for this example.

Comment: I dont know it is possible with a single query in Linq. But i made with a single raw sql command.

Thanks Buddies  :P

Comment: @GiladGreen  Thanks..  :P

Comment: @Gilad Green  the effort what i have put is on sql query..and i have succeeded on that..if you have that much knowledge please convert this into a single Linq and show me..

Comment: @hbulens I suggest you read _[Stance on answering “bad” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281793/stance-on-answering-bad-questions)_ and _[Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)_.  Don't like the rules, then I suggest you go ask over at Social MSDN.  Good luck getting quality answers

Comment: @AjithCholayil  I suggest you too read _[Stance on answering “bad” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281793/stance-on-answering-bad-questions)_ and _[Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)_ my arrogant friend.   Don't like the rules, then I suggest you go ask over at Social MSDN. Good luck getting quality answers

Answer (score 0):

Achieved the result by something like this below.

```
       IQueryable<Sales> query = null;
       StringBuilder Query = new StringBuilder();

        Query.Clear();
        Query.Append("select *" + Environment.NewLine);
        Query.Append("from" + Environment.NewLine);
        Query.Append("(" + Environment.NewLine);
        Query.Append("    select brand, item, sum(qty) as qty, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by brand order by sum(qty) desc) as row_num" + Environment.NewLine);
        Query.Append("    from sales" + Environment.NewLine);
        Query.Append("    group by brand, item" + Environment.NewLine);
        Query.Append(")t" + Environment.NewLine);
        Query.Append("where row_num <= 3" + Environment.NewLine);
        Query.Append("order by brand asc, qty desc" + Environment.NewLine);

        DataTable dt = GetDataTable(db, Query.ToString());

        query = (
                from rw in dt.AsEnumerable()
                select new Sales
                {
                    item = rw.Field<string>("item"),
                    brand = rw.Field<string>("brand"),
                    qty = rw.Field<int>("qty")
                }
              ).AsQueryable();


    public DataTable GetDataTable(DbContext context, string sqlQuery)
    {
        DbProviderFactory dbFactory = 
        DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(context.Database.Connection);

        using (var cmd = dbFactory.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = context.Database.Connection;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
            using (DbDataAdapter adapter = dbFactory.CreateDataAdapter())
            {
                adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(dt);

                return dt;
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this query will work only with MS Sql server.
Once again thanks buddies.. :D